# Read string from file and convert into an int

Tags: string, bash, int

I have a txt file with ONLY a number inside; it can be any number, how can i read it from bash and convert it into an int?

As i said, the only thing in the file is the number, no other thing, but when reading it, bash gets it as a string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bash will automatically treat a string as an integer when you use it in an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Nop, i've tried it and it doesn't; otherwise i won't be asking here :)

Comment: Show your code that fails, you're probably doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `declare` or `typeset`:

```
typeset -i variable=$(cat filename)
```

Comment: @user2266881 Just a comment, the only thing `-i` does is allow the RHS of an assignment to that variable to behave as an arithmetic expression without the need for `$(...)`. It doesn't affect the usage of the variable at all.